# How to get the instance of a ion-slides

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 `ion-slides`, and would like to call some instance methods on it. I have the following markup:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-slides (ionDidChange)="onSlideChanged($event)" id="loopSlider">
   <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
    <h1>{{ slide.title }}</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

I have tried using the following code I found in a (perhaps outdated) example:

```js
 private gotoSlide(index: number): void {
   this.sliderComponent = this.app.getComponent('loopSlider');
   this.sliderComponent.slider.slideTo(index);
  }
```

but `this.app.getComponent('loopSlider');` always returns `null`.

Does anyone know how to get the component instance so I can use its API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [the Ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/), you can do this using [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html):

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
...

@Component({
  ...
})
class MyPage {
  @ViewChild('loopSlider') sliderComponent: Slides;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for that! And there it is right in the doco (that I missed)

Comment: For everybody still running into problems: make sure you really have imported `Slides`!

Answer (score 9):

Now that Ionic4 has been out for a while it's probably frugal to update answers like this, for it.

```
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

export class...
@ViewChild(IonSlides) productSlider: IonSlides;
```

Comment: I can't believe they didn't even bother to update their documentation on this. Thanks a bunch.